# OnClick method not firing on first click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The `onClick` methods for all the `Buttons` and `ImageButtons` that I use do not fire on the first click and the page refreshes instead. The buttons work fine on the second click.

**Markup:**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="yButton" runat="server" Height="56px" Text="" Width="269px" ImageUrl ="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRRcyFHSX9PkLkdwxeABW8vxOcm0BXnXuoU6PB_UfeimATDkKz9Zg" style="margin-left: 0px" EnableViewState="false" CausesValidation="false" OnClick ="YesButton_Click"/>
```

**VB code:**

```
Protected Sub YesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles yButton.Click
        MsgBox("yes button clicked" & answer)
        FormStart.answer = 0
```

```
    answer = 0
    FormStart.answered.Insert(index, 0)
    Dim form As FormStart
    form = New FormStart()

    GoBackButton.Visible = False
    yButton.Visible = False
    nButton.Visible = False
    labelQ.Visible = False
    Me.Visible = False
    FormStart.index = index
    FormStart.GoBack = False
    FormStart.resumeTest = True
    Server.Execute("FormStart.aspx")
End Sub
```

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If (GoBack) Then
            GoBack = True
            FormStart.GoBack = True
            Dim form As FormStart
            form = New FormStart()
            Me.Visible = False
            FormStart.resumeTest = True
            Server.Execute("FormStart.aspx")
        Else
            FormStart.GoBack = False
            AskQuestion(FormStart.quesList(FormStart.index))
        End If
    End Sub

Also the button is made visible on `page_load` like this

```
yButton.Visible = True
```

Comment: What else is in your page_load? Remember: all server-side events cause the _entire page_ to be re-built from scratch, including the full page life cycle methods, like page_init, page_load, etc. Control events aren't until almost the end of this process, so stuff that happens earlier in the lifecycle can interfere with them.

Comment: Oh, and `MsgBox()` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It might seem to work in development, but only because your web server is on the same machine as your browser. When you actually deploy that, the message will only show in a special hidden desktop on the server, the process will freeze until killed or someone actually goes to the web server closes the box.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I added the code for `Page_Load` in the question. In the `AskQuestion` method I initialize a `Label` and an `ImageButton` and then set some of their parameters like `Visible` and `ImageUrl`.  I also specify the yButton's `ImageUrl` and set the `ImageButton` to be visible. Could any of these actions be interfering with the button?

Comment: You may need to move `yButton.Visible = True` to the PreInit event.